# Profile can't be null when connecting to datomic

Tags: clojure, datomic

I’m trying to use datomic cloud and using the
[datomic.client.api :as d]
api for it. This is what I’ve done so far:
Create a client:

```
(d/client {
  :server-type :ion
  :region "us-east-1"   
  :system "humboi-march-2021"
  :creds-profile "humboi"
  :endpoint "http://entry.humboi-march-2021.us-east-1.datomic.net:8182"
  :proxy-port 8182
  })
```

And I evidently have the humboi named-profile in my ~/.aws/credentials:

```
[humboi]
aws_access_key_id = foobar
aws_secret_access_key = foobarbaz
```

But when I run this:

```
(d/create-database
              client
              {:db-name "humboi-march-2021"})
```

Amongst a lot of logs, I get this exception:

```
Execution error (ExceptionInfo) at datomic.client.api.async/ares (async.clj:58).
profile file cannot be null
```

Why am I getting this exception? It seems that the app can't get the aws credentials. Why is this and how can I fix it?

I've also tried manually exporting the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxx AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=yyy environment variables, but still get the same error.

Comment: Do you want to use the Ion or Cloud version? I guess with the Ion version you cannot create databases, only create/query Ion functions on already databases created. Try to change the type to `:cloud`.

Comment: I tried changing to :cloud. I'm still getting the same error

Comment: What are your dependencies? Your deps.clj please

Comment: When you run `aws configure list` your keys are loaded?